# Redirect with www. not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have moved to a new server and now when I enter a URL without www my redirectRule set in .htaccess seem to work fine, but if I add www. I get an error:

> The page isn’t redirecting properly

My rule looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^proj(.*)$ /incl/selectTest.incl.php?proj=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

also I have commented out my redirect to www

```
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.my-domain.com
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.my-domain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

Perhaps somewhere on the server it still adds directiveds. I use WHM for entire VPS. Stuck and need help.

Comment: Test it using command line curl or a new browser.

Comment: Could you please send an example curl line? Thanks.

Comment: `curl -Lk 'http://example.com/'`